# Blog issue - The type or namespace name 'Entries' could not be found

Tags: .net, azure, razor, c1-cms

Apparently without any changes being made, I get the following error in the Composite C1 console on a page which uses the `Composite.Community.Blog.BlogRenderer` Razor function:

[image]

```
Invalid function call - The type or namespace name 'Entries' 
could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly
reference?)
```

The source code of the page in question:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <f:function name="Composite.Community.Blog.BlogRenderer" xmlns:f="http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0">
            <f:param name="BlogListOptions" value="Show image,Show teaser,Show author,Show date,Show tags,Show share icons,Show RSS" />
            <f:param name="BlogItemOptions" value="Show title,Show image,Show content,Show author,Show date,Show tags,Show share icons" />
        </f:function>
        <br />
        <h3>Themen:</h3>
        <f:function name="Composite.Community.Blog.TagsList" xmlns:f="http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0">
            <f:param name="IsGlobal" value="True" />
        </f:function>
    </body>
</html>
```

There is another blog in the project which shows the same error.

I know what the error means, but as nothing haw changed, I wonder where it comes from and how to start searching for the bug.

The website is hosted on Windows Azure.

1. Are there any updating features in either C1 or Azure which could cause this error to occur out of blue skies?
2. How can I start investigations on the cause of this issue?

Disclaimer: Others have worked in the content section of the C1 Management Console but claim not to have changed anything special or issue related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message is telling us, the problem is related to the namespace. There is no `Entries` namespace in Composite's blog package, there is `Composite.Community.Blog.Entries` namespace.

So, first of all check the `@using` statements in the `Composite.Community.Blog.BlogRenderer` Razor function. By default there should be these two using statements:

```
@using Composite.Community.Blog
@using Composite.Core.WebClient.Renderings.Page
```

Secondly, check if there is `Composite.Community.Blog.Entries` datatype in the 'Data' section of the Composite C1 console.